# Nested JOINs doesn't work

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to set a SQL query as the ComboBox's row source.

Here it is.

```
SELECT Абонементы.НомерАбонемента
  FROM Абонементы
 INNER JOIN (Группы ON Группы.Код = Абонементы.Группа
             RIGHT JOIN Направления ON Направления.Код = Группы.Направление)
 WHERE Абонементы.НомерКарты = [НомерКарты].[Value],
       Направления.Код = [NaprCombo].[Value],
       Абонементы.ДатаОкончания > Date
```

But Access displays a message that I have an error in `JOIN` statement.

What I want: select `Абонементы.НомерАбонемента` from table `Абонементы` which has a `Абонементы.Группа` with `Группа.Направление` equal to `Направление.Код` selected in combobox.

I think I should select `Группы` matching condition from combobos at first and then join them to source table. Maybe I have a problem with parentheses. Maybe I don't understand how nested `JOIN`s work in MS Access.

Data structure is shown on pic.

[image: 1]

## Update

Exact message given by Access: "Syntax error in JOIN operation".

Comment: Please give us the ***exact*** error message.

Comment: Any possibility you could give the table schema in English? at least a name like tblA, tblB and some makesense_field names? Then you can later convert any,suggestive answers to the language you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Абонементы.НомерАбонемента    
FROM Абонементы    
INNER JOIN 
(Группы RIGHT JOIN Направления ON Направления.Код = Группы.Направление)
ON Группы.Код = Абонементы.Группа
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the exact error message, we're flying a little blind.  But I can see one issue to begin with, thanks to your comments about parenthesis...

Hopefully a layout change will make it clear why I moved the paranthesis in this example.  *(It may not be the only issues, but I hope it's a start for you)*.

```
SELECT
  Абонементы.НомерАбонемента
FROM
  Абонементы
INNER JOIN
  (
    Группы
  RIGHT JOIN
    Направления
      ON Направления.Код = Группы.Направление
  )
    ON Группы.Код = Абонементы.Группа
WHERE
  Абонементы.НомерКарты = [НомерКарты].[Value]  AND
  Направления.Код = [NaprCombo].[Value]         AND
  Абонементы.ДатаОкончания > Date
```

**NOTE** I also changed `WHERE x, y, z` to `WHERE x AND y AND z`.

It should actually also work without the parenthesis at all.  *(Although I don't use Access and know it has some 'funny' rules.)*  Hopefully this is a good example of what needs to be encased by the if/when you need them.

Comment: "JOIN expression not supported", that's what it says to me. Ok, I thanks, I'll look this a bit later...

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means sure that this will return the data you want, but what is important is that you have a subquery for one of the JOINs:

```
SELECT  t1.НомерАбонемента 
FROM Направления 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT  Группы.Направление, 
             Абонементы.НомерАбонемента, 
             Абонементы.ДатаОкончания
    FROM Абонементы
    INNER JOIN Группы ON Группы.Код = Абонементы.Группа ) As t1
ON Направления.Код = t1.Направление

WHERE t1.НомерКарты = [НомерКарты] 
AND Направления.Код = [NaprCombo] 
AND t1.ДатаОкончания > Date
```

I suggest you get the query working before you add the WHERE statement. WHERE statements are joined up with AND / OR, not commas. The value property of a control is the default, so you do not have to use a property when you wish to return value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to need a right join. Use inner joins all the way, just give it a correct bracketing:

```
SELECT Абонементы.НомерАбонемента
  FROM (Абонементы
 INNER JOIN Группы ON Группы.Код = Абонементы.Группа)
 INNER JOIN Направления ON Направления.Код = Группы.Направление
 WHERE Абонементы.НомерКарты = [НомерКарты].[Value],
       Направления.Код = [NaprCombo].[Value],
       Абонементы.ДатаОкончания > Date
```

Basically, if the left side of a join is also not a table reference but a join too, it must be enclosed in brackets. For instance, if there are just two tables, no brackets are needed:

```
... FROM A JOIN B ON ...
```

But if you introduce another join, you go like this:

```
... FROM (A JOIN B ON ...) JOIN C ON ...
```

And if there was another one, you would need to bracket the first two joins like this:

```
... FROM ((A JOIN B ON ...) JOIN C ON ...) JOIN D ON ...
```

And so on.

An alternative syntax of

```
... FROM A JOIN (B JOIN C ON ...) ON ...
```

doesn't seem to be supported by (your version of) MS Access, judging by the error message you've [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376249/nested-joins-doesnt-work#comment18265622_13376331) you get (`JOIN expression not supported`).